# Не импортируются изображения в React методом map

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, webpack5

Столкнулся с такой проблемой
Хочу добавить блоки в компонент реакта локальные изображения. Перепробовал многое
Вот сам компонент

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import HeaderImage1 from '../../images/HeaderImage1.jpg';
import HeaderImage2 from '../../images/HeaderImage2.jpg';
import HeaderImage3 from '../../images/HeaderImage3.jpg';
export default function DynamicImages() {
  const [img] = useState([
    {img: HeaderImage1},
    {img: HeaderImage2},
    {img: HeaderImage3}
  ])
  return (
    <div className='header-images'>
      {img.map((key, img) => {
        <img key={key} src={img.img} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Проблема в том что он выводит вот так, но не загружает их на страницу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай код webpack

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin'); 
module.exports = {
  entry: { main: './src/pages/index.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: ''
  },
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
    open: true
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
            options: {
              resources: [
                './src/mixins/mixins.scss',
                './src/mixins/variables.scss',
              ]
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Для начала замените `{img.map((itemImg, key) => { <img key={key} src={itemImg.img} /> })`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, в принципе понял в чем у меня был тупняк.